# How do I crop a drawable in Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin, drawable

For some reason, when I imported a bunch of drawables, Android Studio made the resulting box bigger than the actual image. Does anyone know why this is and what I can do to crop them?

For example, in the image below the blue line shows the box surrounding the word "login". I want that box to be right at the edges of the word "login".

[image]

Comment: Did you import SVGs (and created vector drawables), or did you import bitmaps (e.g., PNGs)?

Comment: The latter. The designer I hired gave me PNGs for these.

Comment: OK. Do the original PNGs have the extra space? If so, that is why the imported images have extra space. And, you can use an image editor on your development machine to crop them before re-importing them (or, tell your designer to make changes, if you prefer).

Comment: @CommonsWare the image wouldn't decrease in quality if I do this, correct?

Comment: PNGs are lossless. The primary way that they "decrease in quality" is if you scale them. So, don't do that. :-)